# Telerik Report TableAdapter use existing stored procedure not showing

Tags: visual-studio, telerik, telerik-reporting

I'm using Visual Studio 2015, I created a new stored procedure in my database. But when I try to create a tableadapter and select the "Use existing stored procedures", my newly created stored procedure is not showing up in the list of stored procedures. Are there any steps I forgot to do?

Answer (score 0):

Got it right now. It seems to be that the stored procedure permission must have the user that is in your web.config/app.config login credentials and allow it to execute the stored procedure.